# Unable to access nested elements and to apply functions in Vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to web development and I'm running into an issue I can't solve...
I'm using Vuejs, Express, MongoDB and Fetch API...

In my script I'm fetching data from my local server:

```
  mounted() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/" + this.$route.params.id)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
              this.data = data
              console.log(this.data.telegram.length)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
  }
```

console.log is working fine.

data is returned like that:

```
{ "_id": "6061ee831114fc4c211678e6", "path": "mypath", "telegram": [ { "date": "2021-03-21T22:00:00.708Z", "followers": 2188 }, { "date": "2021-03-22T18:40:04.751Z", "followers": 2195 } ], "__v": 0 }
```

Then data is stored as:

```
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  }
```

First of all, I'm surprised by the format of my data. I believed it was going to appear as JavaScript Format, meaning without quotes (" ") on keys... I tried to JSON.parse the response but it returns an error like if it was already parsed. Is it normal ?

Also, in my template, I'm unable to access properties of this 'data'.

For example:

```
<p>{{data.telegram[0]}}</p>
```

or

```
<p>{{data.telegram.length}}</p>
```

is returning 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' and 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'.

It seems there is something I have not quite understood...

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.telegram` is `undefined` until your mounted method get a response from the server. I suggest you to replace your template code with a computed property that check if your data has value:

```
<template>
  <p>{{mydata}}</p>
  <p>{{telegramLen}}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
     mydata() {
        if (this.data != [])
           return this.data.telegram[0]
        return "No data"
     },
     telegramLen() {
        if (this.data.length > 0)
            return this.data.telegram.length
        return 0
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought mounted() allowed me to fetch data before rendering ? I tried what you suggested and it worked when I changed mounted() to beforeMount() but still mentioning "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in the console. However, this is not exactly my issue: I already have access to 'data' in my template. If i do {{ data }} I have the whole response but I can't access to data.telegram[0] or anything nested...

Comment: [Here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) you can find the lifecycle of a vue component. If you want to fetch data before rendering you should try to use `created` hook instead of `beforeMount`. Otherwise, if you are using vue-router, you can add the [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) `beforeRouteEnter` and move your call to the server here, so that when it renders your component data have already been fetched.
I think that you can't access data.telegram[0] or anything nested because of the undefined before fetching

Comment: Ok thank you, I really need to learn more about hooks !